# триггер удаления строки в MySQL

Tags: mysql, события

Помогите пожалуйста!

У меня есть таблица, и нужно чтобы если в таблице удалится какая либо строка, то необходимо в переменную PHP получить id этой строки (id строки идет по порядку)

*Заранее спасибо!*

**Пример таблицы:**

```
ItsMyTableName

1 MyText
2 ItsAnotherText
3 IneedHELP
4 plsHELPme =)
```

Comment: *если в таблице удалится какая либо строка, то необходимо получить id этой строки* Получить, я извиняюсь, КУДА? триггеры - они ничего никуда вернуть не в состоянии. Впрочем, в триггере можно установить значение какой-либо UDV... правда, если удаляется более одной записи, придётся накапливать значения в каком-то формате, да и перед запросом на удаление чистить переменную - но можно, можно.

Comment: @Akina, в переменную PHP хотелось бы, но я о тригерах узнал буквально час назад, и не нашел ответа, поэтому обратился в форум, с надеждой найти ответ как это можно реализовать все

Comment: *в переменную PHP хотелось бы* MySQL вообще не в курсе, что где-то там далеко есть какой-то там PHP...

Comment: @Akina, \! echo "php php.php?id=1" >> /log/yourlog.txt

Какой смешной

Comment: И каким боком тут MySQL?

Comment: @Akina, DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg1 AFTER INSERT ON `your_table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
\! echo "php php.php?id=1" >> /log/yourlog.txt
END $$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: @Akina, a в php с помощию _GET получаю переменную

Comment: Либо это используется некое нестандартное расширение MySQL, либо всё закончится ошибкой синтаксиса.

Comment: @Akina, у ребят получилось все, вызвать php возможно, как только проверю, отпишусь, уверен что этот способ прлностью рабочий